# Trying to insert elements into view (HTML) from controller ($scope) in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to insert a dictionary (array of objects) into the view in my project . The view is called "product", the controller is called "ProductCtrl".

The output I want to show is just static data. Below is my code:

```js
/*
* "product" module.
*/
'use strict';

angular.module('myApp.products', ['ngRoute'])

.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
  $routeProvider.when('/products', {
    templateUrl: 'products/products.html',
    controller: 'ProductCtrl'
  });
}])

.controller('ProductCtrl', [function($scope) {
//the problem is that I wanna insert those elements using angular and I cannot.
  $scope.productos=[
  {titulo:"1111", descripcion:"!", precio: 25.95, imagen: "camisetas2.png"},
  {titulo:"2222", descripcion:"!A", precio: 25.95, imagen: "camisetas3.png"}
  
  ];

}]);
```

```html
<!--("Producto" View-HTML)-->

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div class="row" ng-controller="ProductCtrl">
 <div class="col-md-12">
 
  <div class="row" ng-repeat="producto in productos"> <!-- Basic for loop -->
      <div class="col-md-12">
      
      <!-- Inicio del contenido; se exponen la empresa y sus servicios (9/4 grid system) -->
       <h2>{{ producto.titulo }}</h2>
       <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-2">
         <img width="120" height="120" alt="mundo camis" src="img/mundo.jpg" class="img-circle">
        </div>
        
        <div class="col-md-10">
         <div class="caption">
          <h3> {{ producto.titulo }} </h3>
           <p> {{ producto.descripcion }}  </p>
          
          <p> <a class="btn-primary" href="#">Ver más</a> </p>
         </div>
        </div>
       </div>
      </div>
     </div>
     <br /> <br />
  
 </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: So, what's your problem/expectation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You had a few mistakes, and the most important - not setting the `ng-app` attribute. I made a simple example for you to use. Code below, link here: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/GoqWyM. 
I advise learning Angular from the following tutorial: http://campus.codeschool.com/courses/shaping-up-with-angular-js/ .

The answer:

```js
/*
* "product" module.
*/
'use strict';

var app = angular.module('Products', []);

app.controller('Producto', [function() {

  this.productos=[
  {titulo:"1111", descripcion:"!", precio: 25.95, imagen: "camisetas2.png"},
  {titulo:"2222", descripcion:"!A", precio: 25.95, imagen: "camisetas3.png"}
  
  ];

}]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="Products" class="row" ng-controller="Producto as ProdCtrl">
  <div ng-repeat="producto in ProdCtrl.productos">
    {{ producto.titulo }}
  </div>
</div>
```